# Can I have a Signal list in PySide6?

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I have a customized QLabel that can be clicked:

```
class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    l_clicked = Signal()
    r_clicked = Signal()
    m_clicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.style_sheet = 'QLabel {background-color: pink}'
        self.alignment = Qt.AlignCenter

    def mouse_press_event(self, ev: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if ev.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.r_clicked.emit()
        elif ev.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.l_clicked.emit()
        elif ev.button() == Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.m_clicked.emit()

    def set_buttons_functions(self, *funcs):
        signals = [self.l_clicked, self.r_clicked, self.m_clicked]
        for func, signal in zip(funcs, signals):
            signal.connect(func)
```

It works fine.

Now I want to make three Singnal()s a list, so the code counld be like this:

```
class ClickedLabel(QLabel):
    signals = [Signal()] * 3

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.style_sheet = 'QLabel {background-color: pink}'
        self.alignment = Qt.AlignCenter

    def mouse_press_event(self, ev: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        buttons = [Qt.LeftButton, Qt.RightButton, Qt.MiddleButton]
        self.signals[buttons.index(ev.button())].emit()

    def set_buttons_functions(self, *funcs):
        for func, signal in zip(funcs, self.signals):
            signal.connect(func)
```

Then I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtCore.Signal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: No, you can't, not like this. Signals *must* be actual class attributes in order to become objects *bound* to the instance (which is a stated requirement). Also, your `mouse_press_event` won't be called since it's not an actual override (it should be `mousePressEvent`), and if you're trying to do some monkey-patch for that (`someWidget.mousePressEvent = someWidget.mouse_press_event`), then be aware that it's not a wise option, and there's absolutely no point in doing that when you can just override the *actual* function.

Comment: If you want to "simplify" the way signals are selected, then just use a dictionary at the class level: `signals = {Qt.LeftButton: l_clicked, Qt.RightButton: r_clicked, Qt.MiddleButton: m_clicked}`, and also ensure that the signal *actually* exists: `signal = self.signals.get(event.button())` `if signal: signal.emit()`. Also, you should ***not*** use [`buttons()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#buttons), but [`button()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#button): the former returns the **currently** pressed buttons, but what you should be interested in is the button that *caused* the event.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you. I am using pyside6's `snake_case`  feature so `mouse_press_event` works properly, it did not showed in the code, my apologise.

Comment: Be aware that the `snake_case` feature has actually been unwelcome for many developers, as it's inconsistent with the official API (not to mention that it makes looking for documentation more difficult). I, for one, strongly discourage its usage, and really hope that they'll remove its support sooner or later. While I can understand its motivations, I don't believe it brings actual benefits: Qt names are already *extremely* verbose (and long); the `snake_case`, while consistent with some PEP conventions (which are **not** mandatory), just complicates things, and unnecessarily.

Comment: In fact, even if the [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) suggests to always use the snake_case, it also allows the mixedCase: "mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that’s already the prevailing style". While they also specify that it's allowed "to retain backwards compatibility", the Qt API convention prevails with its default usage of mixed case. Truth is, there's no real benefit (apart from personal habit) for that feature. And when sharing code with others (like here on SO), the *standard* (aka: the default API) syntax is always preferred.

Comment: @excper The structure of your code is completely backwards. There should be only *one* signal defined as `clicked = Signal(Qt.MouseButton)`. The mouse-press handler can then simply do `self.clicked.emit(ev.button())`. This means you also only need *one* slot to connect to the signal, which receives the `MouseButton` as an argument. The slot can then decide what to do based on which button was pressed. Doing things this way follows the design principle of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: @excper On the snake-case feature: note that your code will simply *never* work in pyqt5/pyqt6, so it's totally unacceptable to use such tags on SO if you insist on using snake-case. Please therefore always convert your code to normal Qt-casing before posting to SO (or just altogether avoid crippling your code with this abominable feature, full stop).

Comment: @musicamante Indeed. I  met strange issues when I used `snake_case` a few days ago. I decide not to use it anymore. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ekhumoro thannks for your suggestion. I've refactored my code as you said, it's better than before. As regards the snake-case feature, I am sorry for I did not know it's only a pyside6 feature, I've removed the pyqt5 tag, and will not use it anymore.

Comment: @excper No problem. It's fine to add pyqt tags with pyside - just not if you're going to post code that uses snake-case (which is quite a divisive feature). I'm glad you found the other comments helpful.